# How can I render a tooltip / hint button in Magento 2 Module Configuration?

Tags: magento2, configuration, uicomponent

How can I create a tooltip button in the configuration section of a custom module? Is it possible to use UI Components to define it?

What I'd like to achieve is for example

for the field defined in `/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
        <field id="xml_filename" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
            <label>XML Filename</label>
        </field>
```

to add a hint

```
The file will be saved under directory ..... etc etc
```

I haven't noticed any such hints in other default magento modules' configuration tabs for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use      `<tooltip>` tag for this.

```
<tooltip>The file will be saved under directory ..... etc etc</tooltip>
```

For example,

```
              <field id="test" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Test Textbox</label>
                    <tooltip>The file will be saved under directory ..... etc etc</tooltip>
                </field>
```

You can find in core magento from below path,

`app\code\Magento\Paypal\etc\adminhtml\system\express_checkout.xml`

**Sample output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a rookie mistake I didn't think to try the same way as magento 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use **Tooltip**

```
<field id="xml_filename" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
    <label>XML Filename</label>
    <tooltip>The file will be saved under directory ..... etc etc </tooltip>
</field>
```

Or **Comment**

```
<field id="xml_filename" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
    <label>XML Filename</label>
    <comment>The file will be saved under directory ..... etc etc </comment>
</field>
```